# matplotlit colorbar title hangs outside figure

Tags: matplotlib, legend, python-3.8, subplot, colorbar

What is the best way to specify my colorbar legend location while ensuring the legend title is within the figure? Sometimes the location will be upper right, as shown here; but in other plots it will be variable, upper/lower left/right.

It is okay if the solution doesn't use `inset_axes()`.

*Alternative Solution:*
It would also be okay if the colorbar legend is to the right of the subplot, if the "My Legend" title is vertical and on the left, and the tick labels are on the right and horizontal (I don't know how to do that).

Using Python 3.8.

```
## Second Plot
vals2 = ax2.scatter(df.x, df.y, edgecolors = 'none', c = df.z,
            norm = mcolors.LogNorm(), cmap=rainbow)
ax2.set_aspect('equal')
ax2.set_title('Subplot Title', style='italic');
ax2.set_xlabel('x');
ax2.set_ylabel('y');

cbaxes = inset_axes(ax2, width="30%", height="10%", location = 'upper right')
clb = plt.colorbar(vals2, cax=cbaxes, format = '%1.2f', orientation='horizontal');
clb.ax.set_title('My Legend')
```

[image]

Comment: Use `loc=1`  in `inset_axes()` to fix location of the colorbar at `upper-right` location.

Comment: `plt.colorbar(..., label='My Legend')` rather than setting the title?

Comment: @JodyKlymak that puts it on the bottom. I want the same configuration without the dangle.

Comment: You could draw the colorbar, get the axes extent with `ax.get_window_extent`, and then move it to be inside the axes.  It is a bit of messing around, but not too hard.  But if it were me, I'd just put the axes on the right, with the label and ticks on the right.  You may also want to use `ax.inset_axes` which will allow you to place the colorbar in axes or data units: https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.inset_axes.html

Comment: @JodyKlymak how do I put the color bar vertical on the right, with the tick labels on the right and the title on the left?

Comment: You can do that if you want, but it will require manual movement of the colorbar axis location (from "right" to "left"), and then without doubt there will be an overhang there.  Matplotlib colorbar labels are placed next to the numbers - if you want them somewhere else you have to do it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would still prefer to have the colorbar (with tick labels and title) *inside* the subplot; but I did find a way to do the *Alternative Solution*:

```
vals2 = ax2.scatter(df.x, df.y, edgecolors = 'none', c = df.z,
            norm = mcolors.LogNorm(), cmap=rainbow)
ax2.set_aspect('equal')
ax2.set_title('Subplot Title', style='italic');
ax2.set_xlabel('x');
ax2.set_ylabel('y');
clb = fig.colorbar(slips2, ax=ax2, format = '%1.2g', location='right', aspect=25)
clb.ax.set_ylabel('My Legend')
clb.ax.yaxis.set_label_position('left')
```

The color bar is taller than the subplot because `ax2` is constrained to be equal xy aspect ratio based on the limits in another subplot (`ax1`, not shown).

[image]